# How to write a generic function that passes one argument to then function then called multiple times

Tags: javascript

I have been stuck on this homework:

> Create a generic function that outputs one line of the countdown on
>   the web page, followed by an alert, and receives the data to output as
>   an input parameter.
>   Use that function to output each line of the countdown, and an alert.
>   Please note that you are outputting the countdown to the browser
>   window this time, not to an alert!
>   The alert is only being used to signal when to output the next line

I need help in how to come up with a generic function that passes only one argument and then can be called 13 times. To write a for loop that output the numeric part of a countdown.

Comment: At least post some code you have tried...

Comment: for (var count=10; count >= 1; count--) {
    window.alert();
    document.write(count+"<br />")

Comment: I've use this to write the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key here is that they're asking for "Generic".

That means one function that doesn't have to know anything but what it's doing.
It also ***usually*** means that it shouldn't remember anything about what it did last time, or what it's going to do next time it's called (unless you're writing a generic structure specifically for remembering).

Now, the wording of the specification is poor, but a generic function which:

1. takes (input) data to write
2. writes the input to the page
3. calls an alert

is much simpler than you might think.

```
var writeInputAndAlert = function (input) {
    // never, ever, ***ever*** use .write / .writeLn in the real world
    document.writeLn(input);
    window.alert("next");
};
```

If I was your teacher, I would then rewrite `window.alert` to handle the ***non-generic*** portion.
It's non-generic, because it knows the rules of the program, and it remembers where you are, and where you're going.

```
var countFrom    = 100,
    currentCount = countFrom,
    countTo      = 0;

var nextCount = function () {
    currentCount -= 1;
    if (currentCount >= countTo) { writeInputAndAlert(currentCount); }
};

window.alert = nextCount;
```

### edit

```
var countdownArray = ["ten", "nine", "eight", "Ignition Start", "Lift Off", "We have Lift Off"],
    i = 0, end = countdownArray.length, text = "",

    printAndAlert = function (item) {
        alert();
        document.write(item);
    };

for (; i < end; i += 1) {
    text = countdownArray[i];
    printAndAlert(text);
}
```

This really doesn't need to be any harder than that.
`printAndAlert` is a generic function that takes one input, writes that input and triggers an alert.
You call it inside of a `for` loop, with each value in your array.
That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thank you, for you explanation. The whole exercise is to create a nasa style countdown ten, nine eight, Ignition Start, Lift Off,We have Lift Off. To write one window alert, the alert is only being used to signal when to output the next line. So i'm to use a for loop to display the numeric part of the countdown. I know how to write the for loop but i cant get the whole code to work when i add the rest of the code. So if you can help me with how to start it out then adding the for loop, what that should look like.

Comment: Well, have a look at the function that I put below. Instead of a function, you can just make that a `for` loop. The basic layout of `for` can either go up `(+= 1)` or down `(-=1)`. We're going down. And it looks like: `var start = 100, end = 0, i; for (i = start; i >= end; i -= 1) { doStuff(i); }`. Have a look at that for loop, and think about how you might write that stuff out.  The generic function that writes lines doesn't care what you give it. So all you need to do is give it something. If you've used arrays, then this should be simple: `["Lift Off", "One", "Two", "Three"]`

Comment: for (var count=10; count >= 1; count--) {
    window.alert();
    document.write(count+"<br />")
}

Comment: that is what i use for the for loop, i know how to use the array but i would have 13 arguments to pass. The assignment does not want me to list 13 arguments but list just one exapm;e

Comment: function test_me(one)

Comment: `for (var count=10; count >= 1; count--) { writeInputAndAlert(count); }` Now find a way to pull the actual text that you want to write, and give it to the function, based on what count you're on.

Comment: function test_me (one {
    window.alert(one)
} now to call that function several times

Comment: Create a generic function that outputs one line of the countdown on the web page, followed by an alert, and receives the data to output as an input parameter.
Use that function to output each line of the countdown, and an alert.
Please note that you are outputting the countdown to the browser window this time, not to an alert!  The alert is only being used to signal when to output the next line.
these are the instructions in case i'm explaining something wrong

Comment: `for (var count=10; count >= 1; count--) { writeInputAndAlert(count); }`  ***"Use that function to output each line of the countdown, and an alert."***

Comment: ok here is what i have come up with, now i just need to figure out how to break the lines in the function outputfor (var count=10; count >= 1; count--) {
    window.alert();
    document.write(count+"<br />")}
function createOutputFunction(dataArray)
{
    return function() {
        document.write(dataArray.shift()); 
    };
}

outputFunction = createOutputFunction(["IgnitionStart","LiftOff","WehaveLiftOff"]);

outputFunction();
outputFunction();
outputFunction();

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a function that will allow you to pass the data once, and then you can call that function to output the data line by line.

To do this exactly that way isn't possible, but this method is almost the same:

```
function createOutputFunction(dataArray)
{
    return function() {
        document.write(dataArray.shift()); // This writes the first element of the dataArray to the browser
    };
}

//It can then be used like this
outputFunction = createOutputFunction(["Banana", "Mango", "Apple"]);

outputFunction();
outputFunction();
outputFunction();
```

The "createOutputFunction" function returns a function that can read the "dataArray" variable and print its first element every time it is called.

Comment: Thank you, for you explanation. The whole exercise is to create a nasa style countdown ten, nine eight, Ignition Start, Lift Off,We have Lift Off. To write one window alert, the alert is only being used to signal when to output the next line. So i'm to use a for loop to display the numeric part of the countdown. I know how to write the for loop but i cant get the whole code to work when i add the rest of the code. So if you can help me with how to start it out then adding the for loop, what that should look like.

Comment: Ok using what you said i've written the code. I can't figure out how to break up the line in the function output so they do not print on the same line

Comment: for (var count=10; count >= 1; count--) {
    window.alert();
    document.write(count+"<br />")}
function createOutputFunction(dataArray)
{
    return function() {
        document.write(dataArray.shift()); 
    };
}

outputFunction = createOutputFunction(["IgnitionStart","LiftOff","WehaveLiftOff"]);

outputFunction();
outputFunction();
outputFunction();

Comment: Add <br /> to the end of the "IgnitionStart" etc strings, just like you did for your count part